# How can I redirect main domain to another domain but not include sub domains in the redirect - htaccess

Tags: html, linux, .htaccess, hosting

I have the .co.uk and .com for for my domain and I currently have the .co.uk set-up to redirect to the .com. Whilst this works, I now need to refine this redirect a little so that it does not include any subdomains. So www.domainname.co.uk will redirect to another but subdomain.domainname.co.uk will not redirect.

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `RewriteCond`, something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.\mysite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

For more in-detail information about `RewriteCond`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond